# How do I get a Previous Month last day with Time of 11:59:59PM in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

Here is what I have for the date Parameter.

```
=dateadd("m",0,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),0))
```

I need to set the time to 11:59:59 PM

Answer (score 0):

You could use a date representation of the first day of the current month and then simply subtract a day.

```
DateAdd(Day,-1,Date(Month(Today),1,Year(Today)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got it. Posting here for anyone that needs it:

=DateAdd("s",86399,dateadd("m",0,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),0)))

This gives you the previous full month's last day, with the time set to 11:59:59 PM